# Implement Fuzzy Prefix Full-text matching query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I understand that Elasticsearch tries to avoid using Fuzzy search with prefix matching, and this is also why it doesn't natively support such feature due to its complexity. However, we have a directory search system that solely relies on elasticsearch as a blackbox search engine, and we need the following logic:

E.g. Say the terms are "Michael Pierce Chem". We want to support full text search on the first two terms (with match query) and we also want to do fuzzy on the last term first and then do a prefix match, as if "Chem" matches "chemistry", "chen", and even "YouTube Chen" due to full-text support.

Please give me some advice on the implementation and design suggestions. Current stack is a NodeJS web app with Elasticsearch.

Comment: If it is a directory then you would know all the available departments? Can't you just make that term a drop-down list with all available departments? Just a simple redesign of the app could avoid this requirement I would think

Comment: @sramalingam24 It searches people in organization as well as their other relevant information, such as department and employee code. The goal is to utilize the search functionality. The front-end requirement is just showing the results in tables, but sadly I cannot change the requirement

Comment: Can you post some mock data and the mapping of your index?

Comment: Sure, it is just bunch of JSON with the keys such as name, business units, and their title, etc. All the fields are copy to an `all_fields` field so that it is easier to do full-text search on all terms.